# How can I join 3 mysql tables if table 3 is not related to table 1

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 tables

emb_enquiries

| custref | name | address | moredetails |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | fred | xxx | xxx |
| 234 | john | xxx | xxx |

emb_installs

| custref | installdate | engref |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-01-01 | abc |
| 234 | 2022-01-01 | def |

emb_engineers

| engref | engname |
| --- | --- |
| abc | joe |
| def | mike |

How can I show the full enquiry plus the install date and the engineers name?

The following code works joining the first 2 tables but when I join the third it throws a Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param().

```
$sql = "SELECT emb_enquiries.*, emb_installs.*, emb.engineers.*
FROM emb_enquiries
LEFT JOIN emb_installs ON emb_enquiries.custref = emb_installs.custref
JOIN emb_engineers ON emb_installs.engref = emb_engineers.engref
WHERE $query = ?
ORDER BY emb_enquiries.id DESC";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $value);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

The $query and $value come from a filter page

```
    // show all by default
    $query = "emb_enquiries.display";
    $value = "all";
    $heading = "Show all Enquiries";


    if(isset($_POST['filterbyname'])) {
      $query = "emb_enquiries.name";
      $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['filterbyname']);
      $heading = $value;
      }
    if(isset($_POST['filterbypostcode'])) {
      $query = "emb_enquiries.postcode";
      $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['filterbypostcode']);
      $heading = $value;
      }
    if(isset($_POST['filterbycustref'])) {
      $query = "emb_enquiries.custref";
      $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['filterbycustref']);
      $heading = $value;
      }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Long done nothing with PHP. `bind_param` on an already `mysqli_real_escape_string` escaped string? The bind_param is with `"s"` but `custref` might not be a string but integer. _Added php tag._

Comment: Try adding left to make the second join `left join` like the first. Have you tried running the query in terminal or phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Stop using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. It will damage your data!

Comment: Dharman, thanks for this info.. I thought it was good to use to stop mysql injections but is it not needed if I use prepared statements anyway?

Comment: Thank you Kendle - I put the query into phpMyAdmin and realised I'd called the third table emb.engineers when it was supposed to be emb_engineers and now it works :)